# cant find WSL interpreter in Pycharm add python interpreter screen

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, interpreter, wsl-2

I am following this [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) to use `WSL-2` for my interpreter on Pycharm, however WSL is no where to be seen:

[image]

---

so is docker...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you're using PyCharm Community, WSL and Docker are supported in PyCharm Professional: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/